# Necesito enviar a un array un contador por separado para cada vez que doy click en un item de un listbox

Tags: c#

He intentado este código y no me funciona

```
private void lstIngreso_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            index = lstIngreso.SelectedIndex;
            valor[index] = Convert.ToDecimal(lstIngreso.SelectedItem);
            cantidad[index] = contador++;

            foreach  (int i in cantidad)
            {
                contador = contador++;  
            }
```

Contador lo tengo declarado globalmente así :

```
int contador=0;
```

el listbox se ve así :

```
0.10
0.20
0.30
0.50
1
2
```

la idea es que cuando doy clic en 0.10 por ejemplo tengo que enviar a un arreglo cuantas monedas de 0.10 centavos o cuantas de .20 escogí. Ahora me cuenta pero no aparte por cada valor.

Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Hace algo parecido a lo que queres.. para que usas el ultimo foreach?

Answer (score 0):

Veamos el problema simple que tiene tu logica.

No necesitas ningun contador global.

Para saber donde hizo click, alcanza con ir sumando uno a esa posicion.

Tu contador global, te serviria para saber el total de monedas.

Entonces arreglemos tu codigo a la siguiente forma:

```
private void lstIngreso_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    index = lstIngreso.SelectedIndex;
    valor[index] = Convert.ToDecimal(lstIngreso.SelectedItem);
    //aca le sumamos uno a esa posicion.
    cantidad[index] += 1;
    //Aca sumamos uno al contador global
    contador++;  
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @AdrianaRodriguez leiste el [tour]? recuerda aceptar las respuestas que te sirvieron. de nada!!!!